# Proving $\mathbf x$ is a $n\times 1$ vector and $\mathbf A$ an $n\times n$ matrix, then $\mathbf x'\mathbf A \mathbf x = \text{tr} (\mathbf {Axx}')$

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

If $\mathbf x$ is a $n\times 1$ vector and $\mathbf A$ an $n\times n$ matrix, then $\mathbf x'\mathbf A \mathbf x  = \text{tr} (\mathbf {Axx}')   (\mathbf A'=transpose A) $

Comment: Why you don't try to write down the lhs and rhs and see if they are equal?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=(x_1 x_2...x_n)^t$ and $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$

Then $x^tAx=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n (x_ka_{ik})x_i$

And $ij$th element of $Axx^t$ is $ \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n (a_{ik}x_k)x_j=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n (x_ka_{ik})x_j$

So Trace($Axx^t$)= $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n (x_ka_{ik})x_i=x^tAx$

Comment: @Dr.Mundo You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Trace is invariant under [cyclic permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Trace_of_a_product), $\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr} x^tAx=\tr(x^tAx)=\tr(Axx^t).$

Comment: nice idea. short and sweet.